# Can't run some python file out of directory

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

hello I try run this cloned app out of directory but it's not work :

`https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester`

I cloned this app in /opt/ folder and add chmod -x to theme I try to run them by this command :

`python3 /opt/theHarvester/theHarvester.py`

it's give me this error :

```
  File "/opt/theHarvester/theHarvester.py", line 5, in <module>
    from theHarvester import __main__
  File "/opt/theHarvester/theHarvester/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from theHarvester.discovery import dnssearch, takeover, shodansearch
  File "/opt/theHarvester/theHarvester/discovery/takeover.py", line 1, in <module> 
    from theHarvester.lib.core import *
 File "/opt/theHarvester/theHarvester/lib/core.py", line 238, in <module>
    class AsyncFetcher:
 File "/opt/theHarvester/theHarvester/lib/core.py", line 239, in AsyncFetcher
    proxy_list = Core.proxy_list()
  File "/opt/theHarvester/theHarvester/lib/core.py", line 103, in proxy_list
    with open('proxies.yaml', 'r') as proxy_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'proxies.yaml'`
```

but when I use this command :

`cd /opt/theHarvester/ python3 theHarvester.py`

it's working well .

Comment: `cd /opt/theHarvester/ ` basically changes your working directory to the location of the `theHarvester.py` file and its able to detect `proxies.yaml` within it. When you run it using `python3 /opt/theHarvester/theHarvester.py`, your working_directory is different and `proxies.yaml` might not exist within it.

Comment: Thanks but so how can I fix that ? I need to run this script in one line .

Comment: `cd /opt/theHarvester/; python3 theHarvester.py`

Comment: Inside your python script, rather than referrin to the file as `proxies.yaml`, you can define its absolute path, using the absolute path of the script itself using `__file__`. Basically, `file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'proxies.yaml')`

Answer (score 1):

at the start of your python script add the following lines:

```
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(script_directory)
```

These lines pretend like you run the script from the directory containing the script (which includes `proxies.yaml` as well).